# Unable to select the navigation drawer icons

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Following is my code to create navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_custom" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is that , the toolbar and the drawer layout contents are overlapping. So Im unable to select the drawer icons.

Following is my code to handle navigation drawer clicks

```
public class NavDrawer extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavigationDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Dashboard
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // My orders
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Testimonials
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Notification
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Contact us
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Sync to Server
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        //Logout
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        if (mDrawerList != null) {
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        }
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        )

        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //embed the dashboard fragment
                fragment = new DashBoardFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                //TODO embed the myorders fragment
                fragment = new MyOrdersFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                //embed  testimonials
                fragment = new TestimonialsFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                //embed  notification
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                //TODO contact us
                break;
            case 5:
                //TODO sync to server
                break;
            case 6:
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: describe the code also of java class

Comment: Yes, DrawerLayout will overlap while it is open. Is that the problem, or have you not added an item click listener to your listview?

Comment: yes thats the problem. Drawer layout is overlapping. I have added onClick listener already. I will post what i have tried.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: i have solved it by myself.  Thank to those who tried and also to those who down-voted. It matters a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a Drawer Activity in Android Studio it creates in this way you having it right now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and where app_bar_home.xml will be like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustonActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_home" />
```

now you can put your Framelayout and listview in content_home.xml.

And then set your drawerlayout in onCreate of your drawer Activity like  this

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Hope it Works.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to just wrap the toolbar and FrameLayout within a LinearLayout of vertical orientation. Following is the correct layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_custom" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```